# Sorting based on a criteria Java (Custom Sort)

Tags: java, python, arrays, sorting, comparator

How do I sort an Array based on a criteria?

In Python I can do something like this

```
arr.sort(key=lambda x: x/(10**len(str(x))-1),reverse=True)
```

Example :

arr=[3,30,34,5,9]

After Sorting

arr=[9,5,34,3,30]

How to implement the same using Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, sake, let's assume `arr` is defined as:

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[]{1,2,3,4,5}
```

You could acheive the Java equivalent with:

```
Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.comparingInt((Integer x) -> x/((int)Math.pow(10, x.toString().length()-1))).reversed());
```

if `arr` is a `List<Integer>` then you can do:

```
arr.sort(Comparator.comparingInt((Integer x) -> x/((int)Math.pow(10, x.toString().length()-1))).reversed());
```

Comment: `Arrays.sort(nums, Comparator.comparingDouble((Integer x) -> x/((double)Math.pow(10, x.toString().length())-1)).reversed());`


Slight change to your code worked for me.... Thank you :)

Comment: @PallaviReddyPalwai btw if you're using `Comparator.comparingDouble` you don't need to cast `(double)`, `Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.comparingDouble((Integer x) -> x/(Math.pow(10, x.toString().length()-1))).reversed());`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively if you don't want to modify the existing array `arr`, you can use :

```
int[] sortedArr = Arrays.stream(arr)
        .boxed()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(
                (Integer x) -> x / (Math.pow(10, x.toString().length() - 1))).reversed())
        .mapToInt(i -> i)
        .toArray();
```